# Why isn't the curvature scale in Robertson-Walker metric dynamic?

Tags: cosmology, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, space-expansion, curvature

$$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a(t)^2 \left[ {dr^2\over1-k{r^2\over R_0^2}}+r^2d\Omega^2 \right]$$

This is the FRW metric, here k=0 for flat space, k=1 for spherical space, k=-1 for hyperbolic space. $R_0$ is the curvature scale for the corresponding maximmaly symmetric 3-dimensional space.

why can't $R_0$ be a dynamical $R(t)$?

There seems no problem on symmetry basis since the time slice of the manifold is definitely still a maximally symmetrical space, suiting the requirement of cosmology. Meanwhile this is a distinct new metric because the dynamical $R_0$ can't be simply rescaled away.

Comment: I am sorry -- what is $R_{0}$ here? Cross-sectional curvature I suppose? If so, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216463/why-does-the-flrw-metric-assume-constant-curvature.

Comment: @VaibhavK The post you mentioned raised the same question as mine. But the top answer in the post you mentioned didn't answer the question. He proved that K must be a constant that is independent of position in a single time slice as a result of spatial homogeneity. The question whether K can be dependent on time still persists.

Comment: @VaibhavK there seems no reason it can't be a function of t right? Each time slice has the correct symmetry. And it seems clear that by doing so we have a distinct metric

Comment: @VaibhavK $ds^2=-dt^2+a(t)^2dl^2(t)$it means for different time slices, the three-dimensional space has a different induced metric representing different curvature scale. And it seems to be a valid new metric for cosmology.

Comment: What happens if you just plug the metric with time-dependent $R_0$ into the Einstein equations? What equations of motion do you get for $a(t)$ and $R_0(t)$?

Comment: Have you looked at the geodesics? I would guess that comoving observers are not geodesic.

Comment: @Javier Comoving observers are still geodesic, all $\Gamma_{\ \ 00}^{\mu}$ are zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generalized metric fails to be homogeneous. It's isotropic, but only around the privileged center of the universe ($r=0$).

One way of showing that is to compute the Ricci scalar curvature; you'll see that it depends on $r$ (but it's a nasty calculation).

Informally, you could think of it this way. Imagine a pie-slice-shaped path with two straight edges of equal length that meet at $r=0$, and a curved edge connecting the other ends at fixed $r>0$. Along this path, there are a bunch of comoving galaxies, so as the universe expands, the whole path (made of galaxies) should expand uniformly. But the length of the straight edges depends on $R(t)$ while the length of the curved edge doesn't, so this can only happen if $R(t)$ is constant.

Also note that if $k=+1$ then only $r$ coordinates that are $\le R(t)$ are meaningful, and therefore, if $R(t)$ is not constant, a comoving galaxy at some $r$ strictly between the minimum and maximum of $R(t)$ will find itself suddenly with "nowhere to be" (in its future or its past, or both).

Comment: Well now I am confused -- in the midst of discussions I presumed the OP was specifying a time-dependent cross sectional curvature $k$ -- what is $R_{0}$ here? Is it something like the time-dependent curvature scale $\frac{k}{a^{2}(t)}$?

Comment: @VaibhavK The way OP wrote it isn't standard, but it doesn't really make a difference, since you could just fold $1/R^2$ into $k$ and have $dr^2/(1-k(t)r^2)$, and nothing about the answer would change, except some details in the last paragraph (replace $k=+1$ with $k(t)>0$, etc.).

Comment: @benrg Thanks a lot! Your answer solved my problem. I've checked indeed the Ricci scalar is dependent on r. Also, there is definitely a problem for k=+1 case.

Answer (score 0):

The spatial curvature scale *is* changing in time, because of the factor of $a^2(t)$ multiplying $\frac{dr^2}{1-k\frac{r^2}{R_0^2}}+d\Omega^2$. For example, if you compute the Riemann tensor for the spatial part of the metric, you should find that a typical non-zero component is of order $\mathcal{R} \sim a^2(t) k R_0^{-2}$. In that sense, you see the constant $R_0$ represents an initial condition; the curvature scale *when $a(t)=1$*.

More precisely, the symmetries of the FLRW metric lead you to an ansatz with a spatial metric with uniform curvature, multiplied by an overall time-dependent scale factor.

Comment: Yes, I think that is apparent from the multiplicative factor $a(t)$, but I think the person is asking if $R$ is _intrinsically_ time-dependent. I don't think this can be so.

Comment: @VaibhavK I see. I am fairly sure you can get rid of a time-dependent $R_0$ by writing $R_0(t) = R_0 f(t)$ for a constant $R_0$ and $f(t)=1$ when $a(t)=1$, then doing a coordinate transformation from $r$ to $\rho$ like $\frac{dr}{f(t)} = d\rho$. The physics is that you should get spatial slices with uniform curvature that scale homogeneously with time.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how this would be time-dependent naturally. That is what I was trying to point out -- if it were time-dependent, how is it a property of a particularly hypersurface $\Sigma (t)$? I am now realising I may have assumed it wrong, but are there examples with some time-dependent $k$?

Comment: @Andrew As I have mentioned in the question, there seems no obvious way to rescale and absorb the time dependence f(t), so it would be nice if you can provide an explicit form of the coordinate transformation that can do it. Note that $r'=r/f(t)$ , $dr' \neq dr/f(t)$

Comment: @VaibhavK I don't have time to work out the details atm, but I am fairly sure that the freedom to have a time dependent $R_0(t)$ can be removed by a coordinate transformation. So it has no physical meaning.

Comment: @Bababeluma Yeah I understand now. I don't have time to work out the details right at the moment, but I'm fairly sure you can do a coordinate transformation in this situation to absorb the time dependence of $R_0(t)$.

Comment: @Andrew I found this paper: htps://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09769 that exactly alternates to time-dependent case. Not sure of the precise meaning and outlook of this, but I was not aware of this earlier.

Comment: @VaibhavK Sorry I accidentally closed the discussion window. This paper didn't specifically deal with the issue. Rather the k(t) seems to be an emergent result of the perturbation theory. I might be wrong since I just skimmed it. The dynamical equation for the metric I wrote should look very different from eq17 in the paper. But I'm glad you admit such a possibility.

Comment: @Andrew Please keep me updated if you find such a coordinate transformation.

Comment: @VaibhavK I'll work out the modified Friedmann equation and check new phenomenology tomorrow.

Comment: @Bababeluma Indeed, $k(t)$ is seemingly emergent in this paper. The thing is, since I referred to the other stackexchange answer, I presumed you were talking about a case where a constant spacelike surface had some time-dependent notion of $k$, which is why I was arguing that "a constant $t$ hypersurface cannot be a function of $t$". However, now I understand what you were asking. I will think on this when not working (my work is in hep-th, due to which I am naive about pure GR). Also, do keep me posted (on SE?) on this.